# Mattermost iframe integration Django app

Tags: django, iframe, mattermost

I have apache 2.4 and mattermost 5.2. Both of them are on the same server. I have configured a virtual host for pointing to mattermost on port 8065. Following is my conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.domain.in
  #ServerAdmin hostmaster@mydomain.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Set web sockets
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* wss://127.0.0.1:8065%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  <LocationMatch "^/api/v(?<apiversion>[0-9]+)/(?<apiusers>users/)?websocket">
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8065/api/v%{env:MATCH_APIVERSION}/%{env:MATCH_APIUSERS}websocket
    ProxyPassReverse ws://127.0.0.1:8065/api/v%{env:MATCH_APIVERSION}/%{env:MATCH_APIUSERS}websocket
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.in
  </LocationMatch>

  <Location />
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.in
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to load iframe in following way from anothersubdomain.domain.in/mattermost in Django application

```
<iframe src="http://subdomain.domain.in"></iframe>
```

I am getting

```
Refused to display 'http://subdomain.domain.in/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"
```

I do not want to change in mattermost code. Is there a way to complete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some days with this problem, I have come to solution to edit the request headers of **Content-Security-Policy** and **X-Frame-Options**. Following is my edited virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.domain.in
  #ServerAdmin hostmaster@mydomain.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Set web sockets
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* wss://127.0.0.1:8065%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  Header edit Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors 'self'" "frame-ancestors http://*.domain.in"
  Header edit X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" "allow-from http://*.domain.in"

  <LocationMatch "^/api/v(?<apiversion>[0-9]+)/(?<apiusers>users/)?websocket">
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8065/api/v%{env:MATCH_APIVERSION}/%{env:MATCH_APIUSERS}websocket
    ProxyPassReverse ws://127.0.0.1:8065/api/v%{env:MATCH_APIVERSION}/%{env:MATCH_APIUSERS}websocket
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.in
  </LocationMatch>

  <Location />
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.in
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here, I have edited the headers to be allowed for all subdomain of my domain only.